# A simple javaScript code that dosen't work @_@

Tags: javascript

OK, here is the thing, I wrote a simple code for a slide show, it works and it's as I expected and that's it:

```
var slideShowImage = document.getElementById("slideShowImage");
var images = ["_Images/Image_01.jpg","_Images/Image_02.jpg","_Images/Image_03.jpg","_Images/Image_04.jpg","_Images/Image_05.jpg","_Images/Image_06.jpg","_Images/Image_07.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage (){
    slideShowImage.setAttribute ("src",images[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= images.length){
            imageIndex = 0;
        }   
    }

setInterval (changeImage,3000);
```

But as I'm still learning javaScript I thought to change the logic to taste myself, and I rewrote the code, but it doesn't work, I have no idea why...
Hopefully someone can enlighten me with why it doesn't...

```
var imageId = document.getElementById("slideShowImage");
var imageNumber = 1;
var imageName = "_Images/Image_0"+imageNumber+".jpg";

function changeImage (){
    imageId.setAttribute("Src",imageName);
    imageNumber++;
    if (imageNumber==7){
        imageNumber=1;
        }
    }
setInterval(changeImage,1000);
```

Comment: Did you add this event dom load? I mean wrap them in a function then register it on window.onload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in second approach the var imageName is assigned to a static value i.e "_Images/Image_0"+imageNumber+".jpg", as per the first answer you need to recalculate the value of this variable.

instead you can write imageName as function which returns the calculated value

```
var imageName = function(){ return "_Images/Image_0"+imageNumber+".jpg"; }
```

and call inside changeImage

```
function changeImage (){
    imageId.setAttribute("Src",imageName());
    imageNumber++;
    if (imageNumber==7){
        imageNumber=1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome!! it works, first time to know about the static thingy :P

Though why did you use the parentheses after the var name?

Comment: that's copy pasted from question, removed it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!
I meant over there, the var name inside, I see that you used two parentheses after the var name (): imageId.setAttribute("Src",imageName());

Comment: that is the call of function. The var imageName is a function and you need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageName = "_Images/Image_0"+imageNumber+".jpg";
```

You need to update `imageName` each time the number changes. Otherwise this string is fixed to Image_01.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Your `imageName` variable is never being updated. You have to update it on each chageImage call.

```
var imageId = document.getElementById("slideShowImage");
var imageNumber = 1;
var imageName = "_Images/Image_0"+imageNumber+".jpg";

function changeImage (){
    imageNumber++;
    imageName = "_Images/Image_0"+imageNumber+".jpg";
    imageId.setAttribute("Src",imageName);
    if (imageNumber==7){
        imageNumber=1;
    }
}
setInterval(changeImage,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you've made is that the image name in your version is not evaluated once per iteration.

```
var imageId = document.getElementById("slideShowImage");
var imageNumber = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  imageId.setAttribute("src","_Images/Image_0"+imageNumber+"jpg");
  imageNumber++;
  if (imageNumber == 7) imageNumber = 1;
},1000);
```

This will result in your code actually working. I took the image path and brought it in the function so it gets evaluated on each iteration, which was the main bug.

Bear in mind, your images will not load instantly; Setting them to 1s per transition is unwise. In practice, you want to preload all of them in the background somewhere invisible, which guarantees instant recall.

Answer (score 0):

you can replase your code 
imageId.setAttribute("Src",imageName);
with the follwoing
imageId.src = imageName;